# How come my linking stylesheet isnt working?

Tags: css

Here is some simple HTML for you below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href = "ccs.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class = "fah">
    Purchase!
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Below is some CSS for the code that is an external stylesheet

```
.fah {
  border-style:solid;
 }
```

Can somebody please help me as to why there is no border being created around the DIV, although I linked it using the `"link rel = "stylesheet"` attribute.

Comment: You should probably specify a width for your border. For example: `.fah {border: 1px solid black}`

Comment: why do you have space before and after the equal `href="css.css`??

Comment: A solid border with no color creates a solid border that is the same color as the background. You specified no width or color for your class..

Comment: I tried all three, ended up with the same result, I wrote: .fah{border-style:solid;
border-color:rgb(1,1,100);
border-width:100px;  

 box-shadow:3px 3px 7px #cccccc; 



 }

Comment: Is your style sheet called "ccs.css" or "css.css"? Is that a typo? View your page source in a browser, and make sure the CSS file is accessible.

Comment: @accountstorage Can you produce a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? Your code by itself works as expected. https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/gn8xu9m7/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your CSS file is called `ccs.css` and that its not a typing mistake.

If you do that please give more detail in css. Add `border: 2px solid red;` or something.
Only adding `border-style:solid;` might not give you visible output.